# How do I access google photos from my node js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, picasa, google-data-api, google-photos

I am writing an app to access a user's images on Google Photos.

It seems that there is no 'official' API for Google Photos, however the images can be accessed via the [Picasa Web Albums API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/).

There are no official Google Picasa Web Albums API references/documentation for NodeJS / Javascript.

How can I access this API from my Node app ?

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Photos).

Answer (score 1):

To download the latest 10 photos from google photos, do the first 2 steps of the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs), insert the client secret, client id and redirect into the coffeescript below and run it. (`npm install --global coffeescript` then `coffee quickstart.coffee` to run or `coffee -c quickstart.coffee` to compile to javascript)

I think the user has to connect their google photos account with google drive for this to work.

Hints for working with the [Reference (v3)](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files) and google drive in general:

- don't forget the `auth` object when you call api functions that require authentication: `service.files.list({auth:auth, other params here...},callback)` - if you forget, it returns a `Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded` error
- every file has many properties, but in v3 of the Api it doesn't return all the fields of the resource by default. You'll have to specify them via the `fields` option like this: `service.files.get({auth:auth,fileId:"1y3....",fields:"mimeType, webContentLink, webViewLink, thumbnailLink"},callback)`
- if you want to download a file, put `alt:"media"`in the options
- you can query files with the `q` option. Look at the [available serach parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters). Note that you can combine and nest searches via `and`, `or` and `not`.
- there are no real "folders" in google drive. every file can have multiple "parents".

  - you can get the ids of all folders by calling `service.files.list` with the query option `q:'mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"'`
  - to get a folder by name use query `q:'name = "<name of folder>" and mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"'`
  - you could get the id of the root folder by calling `service.files.get({auth:auth, fileId:"root"},callback)` - but you can simply use `root` where you would put this id
  - to list all the things in the root folder call `service.files.list({auth:auth,q:'parents in "root"'},callback)`
  - if you have the id of a file, you can get the folder(s) of the file by calling `service.files.get` with the `fields:"parents"` option
  - you you have the id of a folder you can get the files of this folder by calling `service.files.list` with a query option `q:'parents in "0B7..."'` (note that the id needs `"..."`)
  - listing the files in the folder with the path `/one/two/three` is the same as listing the files of the folder `three` - but you'll need the id of this folder first. you can get this id by iteratively walking down the path

```coffee
fs = require('fs')
readline = require('readline')
google = require('googleapis')
googleAuth = require('google-auth-library')

SCOPES = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' ] # scope for everything :D
TOKEN_PATH = './token.json'
CLIENT_SECRET = <your client secret here>
CLIENT_ID = <your client id here>
REDIRECT = <your redirect url here>

authorize = (callback) ->
    auth = new googleAuth
    oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,REDIRECT)
    # Read the Token at ./token.json or get a new one
    fs.readFile TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) -> 
        if err
            getNewToken oauth2Client, callback
        else
            oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token)
            callback oauth2Client

getNewToken = (oauth2Client, callback) ->
    authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({access_type: 'offline', scope: SCOPES})
    console.log 'Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl

    rl = readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin,output: process.stdout})
    rl.question 'Enter the code in the address bar without the "#"(?code=<code>#)', (code) ->
        rl.close()
        oauth2Client.getToken code, (err, token) ->
            oauth2Client.credentials = token
            fs.writeFile TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token) # store token for later
            callback oauth2Client

authorize (auth)->
    service = google.drive('v3')
    # get ids of the 10 most recent photos
    # every request needs the auth:auth
    service.files.list {auth:auth,pageSize: 10,orderBy: 'createdTime desc',q:"mimeType = 'image/jpeg'"},(err,response)->
        for file in response.files 
            dest = fs.createWriteStream(file.name)
            # you have to add the alt:"media" option to get the file contents
            # if you want a link to the file that can be used in an <img src=''> tag: add fields:"webContentLink"
            service.files.get({auth:auth,fileId:file.id,alt:"media"}).pipe(dest)
```